# Is it possible to add data to a React component using the same prop label more than once, then have the component map that data into list items?

Tags: reactjs, react-props, react-component

[image: list of payment methods]

I'd like to create a reusable component in React that displays a list of what payment methods are available for a certain service.

Is it possible to add the data to the component like this (with multiple uses of the same prop label)?

```
const Page = () => {
    <PaymentMethods method="BACS Transfer" method="Cheque" method="PayPal" method="Credit / Debit Card" />
}
```

Or perhaps it's an array `method=[BACS Transfer, Cheque]`

Either way, I'd like to know if it's possible. If so, what does the component look like to map over the data and output as `<li>` items.

If this is a bad approach, what is the best way to do it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass them as an array, like this:

```
<PaymentMethods methods={["BACS Transfer", "Cheque", "PayPal", "Credit / Debit Card"]} />
```

The component itself should be something such as this:

```
const PaymentMethods = ({methods}) => {
    return <ul>
      {methods.map((method, index) => <li key={index}>{method}</li>)}
    </ul>
}
```

Comment: That's great to know! Thanks. And just to complete the picture, what would the component look like that takes the array and maps over it?

Comment: @DaveMullenJnr Added an example.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to achieve it.

1. put the items on one prop

```
<PaymentMethods
  lists={['BACS Transfer', 'Cheque', 'PayPal', 'Credit/Debit Card']}
/>

////
function PaymentMethods({lists}){
  return (
    <ul>
      {lists.map((text)=>(<li>{text}</li>))}
    </ul>
  )
}
```

2. Using children

```
<PaymentMethods>
  <li>BACS Transfer</li>
  <li>Cheque</li>
  <li>PayPal</li>
  <li>Credit/Debit Card</li>
</PaymentMethods>
```

Comment: **Two great solutions**. Thanks! The array on one prop is what I was hoping for as I want to avoid using `{children}` in this case but still wanted the flexibility to add one, two, or several payment methods. In the array instance, what would the component look like that takes the data, maps over it, and outputs a bunch of `<li>` items?

Comment: Great! Thanks for adding the `map` example.